# php regexp for national domains

Tags: php, regex, dns

Thare are new nations domains and TLDs like "[http://президент.рф/](http://%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/)" - for Russian Federation domains, or [http://example.新加坡](http://example.%E6%96%B0%E5%8A%A0%E5%9D%A1) for Singapore...

Is there a regex to validate these domains?

<s>I have found this one: [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url/190405#190405)</s>

But when I try to use one of the expressions listed there - PHP is getting overhitted :)

```
preg_match(): Compilation failed: character value in \x{...} sequence is too large at offset 81
```

P.S.

1) Last part was solved by **@OmnipotentEntity**

2) But the main problem - to validate international domain - still exists, because example regexp doesn't validate well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no regexp to validate those domains.  Each TLD has different rules about which Unicode code points are permissible within their IDNs (if any).  You would need a *very* big lookup table which would have to be kept up-to-date to know which specific characters are legal.

Furthermore there are rules about whether left-to-right written characters and right-to-left characters can be combined within a single DNS label.

BTW, the RFCs mentioned in the other comments are obsolete. The recently approved set are RFCs 5890 - 5895.

Comment: I see. So right now we don't have any good solutions for domain validation. Right?

Answer (score 3):

Use the "u" modifier to match unicode characters.  The example you gave only uses the "i" modifier.

Comment: But the top problem still exists. The regexp in example validates domain 'http://$$$президент!!!.рф' as a valid domain :(

Comment: I'm not going to lie, looking at that regular expression makes my brain hurt.  But it looks like $ and ! are explicitly allowed in the domain name by the regular expression you're using.  I double checked rfc3986 and 3987, 3986 referenced (via 1123) 952, which defines domain names.  But this was preinternationalization (written in 1985!)  I don't know what characters are allowed postinternationalization, but if you don't want $ and ! to validate in the domain name simply take them out.

Comment: Thats why this question has no solid answer yet :) Who knows what other chatacters that regexp misses, and what else need to be added to make it perfect.